# Unable to locally verify the issuer’s authority on RHEL6.1

Tags: ssl-certificate

Here is the command I execute:

```
wget https://*******.com:8080/view/Build-Oncommit/job/Build-inDC-oncommit/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/dist/indc-harvester-0.3.254385.tar.gz
```

And this is what I get:

```
 --2014-03-28 18:40:45--  https://*******.com:8080/view/Build-Oncommit/job/Build-inDC-oncommit/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/dist/indc-harvester-0.3.254385.tar.gz

  Resolving *******.com... 
**** Connecting to *******|****|:8080...
 connected. ERROR: cannot verify *******’s certificate, issued by
 “/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO
 SSL CA”:   Unable to locally verify the issuer’s authority. To connect
 to *******.com insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’. [*****
 *****]$ cat /etc/redhat-release  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.1 (Santiago)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: The certificate of \`raw.githubusercontent.com' is not trusted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144426/error-the-certificate-of-raw-githubusercontent-com-is-not-trusted)