# ERROR: The certificate of `raw.githubusercontent.com' is not trusted

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate, wget

I am trying to use wget to retrieve some file from github over a remote server (ssh), here is what I get:

```
$ wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aseemk/seadragon-ajax/master/seadragon-min.js
--2014-11-26 09:30:14--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aseemk/seadragon-ajax/master/seadragon-min.js
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 185.31.19.133
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|185.31.19.133|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of `raw.githubusercontent.com' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of `raw.githubusercontent.com' hasn't got a known issuer.
```

Same goes for curl:

```
$ curl -o bla  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aseemk/seadragon-ajax/master/seadragon-min.js
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Using wget option: `--no-check-certificate` seems like a hack, what could I be missing ?

Comment: Check the system clock as well.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The solution was simple, from my debian system simply install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Comment: my beagle bone black revc, which has debain installed on it say `ca-certificates is already the newest version` and the error still persist how to tackle this

Comment: what is the version you are using (eg: `apt-cache policy ca-certificates`) ? The latest is: `20141019` (https://packages.qa.debian.org/c/ca-certificates.html)

Comment: @kakeh ... did you run `sudo apt update;`  first? any errors from `update` ?

Comment: Why is this still an issue in the year 2023? `ca-certificates is already the newest version (20210119)`  and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Update: It seems I'm still getting an older version because my (Bullseye) Debian in now considered `oldstable`, and no new version of `ca-certificates` has been back-ported.

Comment: I also noticed this line on the page linked by `malat` above: `Migration status for ca-certificates (20210119 to 20211016): BLOCKED: Rejected/violates migration policy/introduces a regression`

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on raspbian, fixed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install ssl-cert
```